# Arrange Act Assert Alternatives

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, bdd, arrange-act-assert

The general question is **are there alternative patterns to AAA for unit testing**?
If, yes, would be very interesting to see some examples and hear about their pros and cons.

And as the simplest example of AAA test (in c#, using var for the sake of simplicity):

```
// Arranging
var annualSalary = 120000M;
var period = 3; // for a quarter profit
var calc = new SalaryCalculator();

// Acting
var result = calc.CalculateProfit(annualSalary, period); 

// Assertion
Assert.IsEqual(40000, result);
```

Answer (score 12):

I like something that is not so much an alternative to AAA, but rather a variation.  I think of it as *Arrange-Assert(not)-Act-Assert*, but others have called it a *Guard Assertion*.  The idea is to have an assertion that ensures the desired result of the Act is not already present before the act.  There's a good discussion of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021007/should-it-be-arrange-assert-act-assert).

Comment: I can see this technique is not widely used. Have you ever put it in practice in one of your real world production projects?

Comment: I've used it, but not in a particularly disciplined fashion.  Just sometimes when I want to be sure that the action under test is what brings about the condition, sometimes I will write my tests this way.  Not as a regular policy.

Comment: It's an interesting idea; I sometimes use it "informally" when I feel it's important to clarify what the preconditions of the test are.

Comment: I like to call it Assume, so the pattern becomes Arrange-Assume-Act-Assert. (AAAA)

Answer (score 11):

There is another notation from *Behavior-driven development*: **Given** - **When** - **Then**. Examples for c# is [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/specflownew/) and for [Jasmin](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) for JavaScript. Both resource are full of examples of using this notation.  The **GWT** approach is typically used in a Behavior Driven Development and Aspect Oriented Programming.

Comment: I've just checked a few thing over Internet and really seems like the Given-When-Then is the same Arrange-Act-Assert (for example [this](http://hadihariri.com/2012/04/11/what-bdd-has-taught-me/)). They semantically and logically look pretty similar. But the implementation differs exposing a fully explicit attributive way of testing. Nice :)

Answer (score 4):

Some of the earliest mocking frameworks (in the .Net world at least) forced you to use the [Record/Replay](http://ayende.com/blog/3072/the-record-replay-verify-model) pattern. I say force because I don't find it very natural or readable and there was no alternative back then.

This spawned a new race of isolation frameworks promoting the AAA form, which I find to be the most intent-revealing approach. More about this [here](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/whats-wrong-with-the-recordreplyverify-model-for-mocking-frameworks/).

Comment: Nice snapshot from history. I'm working on .net platform from the very first version and I can't remember if I've made use of one of those earliest mocking frameworks back that days. Neither one of my team members ever worked with.

Answer (score 1):

when you are using parameterized testing then often you can move 'arranging' or 'given' part to parameters. but still, the principle remains

Answer (score 1):

Another common pattern used in unit testing is **Four Phase Test Pattern**:

1. Setup
2. Execute
3. Check
4. Teardown

The first steps are essentially the same as in the AAA Pattern. However, I find the Four-Phase Pattern better suited to languages where you have to clean up after yourself, for example, C or C++. Step 4 (teardown) is where you free any allocated memory, or destroy objects you created for the test.

In situations where you do not allocate any memory, or a garbage collector takes care of deallocation, the fourth step goes unused most of the time, so it makes more sense to use the AAA Pattern.

In C++, for example, the above test might be:

```
// Setup
int annualSalary = 120000;
int period = 3; // for a quarter profit
int result;
SalaryCalculator calc = new SalaryCalculator();

// Execute
result = calc.CalculateProfit(annualSalary, period); 

// Check
CHECK_EQUAL(40000, result);

// Teardown
delete calc;
```

Comment: You could call it Arrange-Act-Assert-Absterge :) Absterge was the only synonym for cleaning that started with an a that I could find. Maybe you could make an argument in favor of disAssemble, but that is just cheating I'd say :p