# Junit failed tests, how to fix this?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

So I'm tesing using Junit, quite new to it.
I am trying to test methods in a class called SetOfUsers as follows:

```
 @Test
    public void testFindUserByName() {
        System.out.println("findUserByName");
        String name = "";
        SetOfUsers instance = new SetOfUsers();
        User expResult = null;
        User result = instance.findUserByName(name);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.

    }
```

So I wanted to check the name of a user entered in Bob for instance in the name string like this

```
String name = "Bob";
```

since I have a user called Bob in  the setOfUsers class.
The output window displays this message

```
Failed: expected:<null> but was:<Staff name:Bob, Staff pass:abc123>
```

What can I do to make this a pass?

Comment: Well, given that `expResult` is null...

Comment: Where is "Bob" string assigned?

Comment: In another class called setOfUsers

Comment: The first thing you have to consider is what specific scenario are you trying to test? Right now, it looks like you are trying to test what happens when someone tries to find a user in a (presumably empty??) SetOfUsers() and you're expecting the returnvalue to be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development), this is very nice technique for making tests easy to write and understand (read)

> Test-driven development is a software development methodology which essentially states that for each unit of software, a software developer must:
>
> - define a test set for the unit first;
> - then implement the unit;
> - finally verify that the implementation of the unit makes the tests succeed.

Well written test should have [GivenWhenThen](http://guide.agilealliance.org/guide/gwt.html) sections

> (**Given**) some context
>
> (**When**) some action is carried out
>
> (**Then**) a particular set of observable consequences should obtain

This style is known as [SpecificationByExample](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/GivenWhenThen.html)

> Given-When-Then is a style of representing tests - or as its advocates would say - specifying a system's behavior using SpecificationByExample.

### Example test

```
@Test
public void testFindUserByName() {

    // given
    SetOfUsers instance = new SetOfUsers();

    // when
    User result = instance.findUserByName("Bob");

    // then
    assertEquals("Bob", result.getName());

}
```

Nice to read:

- [Arrange Act Assert Alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990615/arrange-act-assert-alternatives)
- [Maintainable Tests](http://www.slideshare.net/tomek_k/sample-chapter-of-practical-unit-testing-with-testng-and-mockito)

Answer (score 1):

This test is always going to fail because the last line is

```
fail("The test case is a prototype.");
```

The reason your test is failing now is because of the line above,

```
assertEquals(expResult, result);
```

You are setting your expected result to null and the result you are getting from the name, `""`, is probably an empty String as well from that error message. You need to have expResult to be the same as what you expect instance.findUserByName("Bob") to return. However, unless you initialize the instance to be set with a User Object the objects will not match, so it might be better to either mock it to return a pre-created `User` object so they match, or create a `User` object with the same properties as the one you expect to be returned check the fields of the `User` Object returned and the `User` object you created to be sure they match.

If you want to check for what the user for `Bob` is, change the code to this:

```
@Test
public void testFindUserByName() {
    System.out.println("findUserByName");
    String name = "Bob";
    SetOfUsers instance = new SetOfUsers();
    User expResult = <Create an object you expect instance.findUserByName("Bob") to return>;
    User result = instance.findUserByName(name);
    //Check fields here.
    assertEquals(expResult.getUserName(), result,getUserName());
    // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't test for null using `assertEquals()`.
To test for null, use:

```
assertNull(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question, but if you want to search for "Bob" why you initialize name=""? The test should be:

```
@Test
public void testFindUserByName() {
    //Create SetOfUsers
    //Add new User with name Bob
    //FindByUsername("Bob")
    //AssertEqual(User.getName(), "Bob")
}
```